# save updated models to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following code to fetch some data from the db (mongo).

```
function getAllUsers(){
    var UsersPromise = Q.defer();

    UserSchema.find({}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            UsersPromise .reject(err);
        }else {
            UsersPromise .resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return UsersPromise .promise;
}
```

Then I modify each of these models. I add certain fields to the model depending on the type of user. (This is working correctly).

```
function buildUsers(users){
    // my code iterates over users and adds
    // properties as required.
    // Working fine.
    return users; // updated users.
}
```

Now I want to save these updated models back to mongo and this is where it's making me pull my hair.

```
function saveUsers(users){
    // here, the users are received correctly. But the following line to save the users fails.
    var SaveUsersPromise = Q.defer();
    UserSchema.save(users, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            SaveUsersPromise .reject(err);
        } else {
            SaveUsersPromise .resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return SaveUsersPromise .promise;
}
```

Lastly I call these functions like:

```
DB.connect()
.then(getAllUsers)
.then(buildUsers)
.then(saveUsers)
.catch(errorHandler);
```

Everything works correctly untill I call `UserSchema.save`. What could be the problem?

PS: I am using `mongoose`.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserSchema.save` accepts single instance, you have to loop through users and save each. Mongoose doesn't have bulk inserts implemented yet (see [issue #723](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/723)).

Here's simple implementation using [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
function saveUsers(users){
    var async = require('async');  // <== npm install async --save
    var SaveUsersPromise = Q.defer();
    async.eachSeries(users, function(user, done){
        UserSchema.save(user, done);
        // or
        user.save(done); // if user is Mongoose-document object
    }, function(err){
        if(err){
            SaveUsersPromise.reject(err);
        } else {
            SaveUsersPromise.resolve();
        }
    });
    return SaveUsersPromise.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Will look into it and let you know. :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although, I had to use `async.forEachOf` instead of `async.eachSeries`. Thanks again. :)